# SQLAlchemy filtered relationship property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I’m looking for a way to have a filtered property for a more general relationship — perhaps best explained in some code:

```py
class Content(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    collection_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("collection.id"), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, index=True)
    weight = db.Column(db.Integer())

class Collection(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    items = db.relationship(
        "Content",
        backref="collection",
        collection_class=sqlalchemy.ex.orderinglist.ordering_list("weight")
    )
    poems = "items filtered by type='poem'"
```

`Collection.poems` should in this case behave exactly the same as `Collection.items` except for being filtered. This means ideally write operations would propagate between those two:

```py
collection = Collection(items=[
  Content(title="foo", type="other"),
  Content(title="bar", type="poem"),
])
assert [c.title for c in collection.items] == ["foo", "bar"]
assert [c.title for c in collection.poems] == ["bar"]
collection.poems.append(Content(title="baz", type="poem"))
assert [c.title for c in collection.items] == ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

I have tried:

- Using a [hybrid_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property) for this but of course appending new items didn’t work this way.
- Using a separate `db.relationship()` but then the relationship collections don’t populate one another